# How to call a variable with JSP?

Tags: java, jsp, intellij-idea

In JSP I have created a simple variable like this:

```
<%
    if (request.getSession().getAttribute("user") != null) {
        String status = "online";
    }
    else {
        String status = "offline";
    }
%>
```

In HTML I call the variable like this: `${status}`

So the string "offline" or "online" would just be a CSS class, as you see in the code below:

```
<img class="profile-pic" src="../assets/img/reza.png" alt="Chin"> <i class="status ${status}"></i>Reza
```

So the whole code looks like this:

```
<%
    if (request.getSession().getAttribute("user") != null) {
        String status = "online";
    }
    else {
        String status = "offline";
    }
%>
    <div class="user-section">
        <img class="profile-pic" src="../assets/img/reza.png" alt="Chin"> <i class="status ${status}"></i>Reza
    </div>
```

but from Intellij I get the warning:

> Cannot resolve variable 'status'

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a problem with scopes, when you declare a variable inside an if or else block you can use this variable just in that scope, you can solve your issue like so :

```
<%
    String status = "offline"; // declare the variable outside the if else
    if (request.getSession().getAttribute("user") != null) {
        status = "online"; // if the condition is correct then assign "online"
    }
%>
```

---

***After your edit***

It seems you are using the variable name with a wrong way, instead you have to use :

```
<i class="status <%=status%>">
```

Instead of :

```
<i class="status ${status}">
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried that out but I still get the same warning.

Comment: @Ray can you show us more code so we can understand better your issue?

Comment: @Ray in this case you can use `class="status <%=status%>"`

Answer (score 1):

Per your updated code, you need to reference "status" like this in your HTML:

```
<div class="user-section">
    <img class="profile-pic" src="../assets/img/reza.png" alt="Chin"> <i class="status <%=status%>"></i>Reza
</div>
```

"JSP" is processed "server side".  It's output is HTML, which is then sent to your browser.

The Java variable "status" is set to the Java string "offline" or "online" on the server.  You can use the JSP tag `<%= %>` to write its value into your HTML stream.

Comment: Thank you. `<%=status>` didn't work for me. I get the error "Attribute value is not closed". But as YCF_L said, I tried it with `<%=status%>` and it works great!